# Phonetic/acoustic difference between /ˈæb.sə.luːt/ and /ˈæp.sə.luːt/

Tags: english, phonology, plosives

My understanding is that "b" in "absolute" can be pronounced either as /b/ or /p/. In both cases, the plosive is usually not released (or has an inaudible release). Clipping occurs in the case of /p/ but also rhythmic clipping happens for /b/, so difference in duration is almost negligible.

For native English speakers, can they notice any difference between /ˈæbs.ə.luːt/ and /ˈæps.ə.luːt/ in normal speech?

Also any physical difference can be spotted between the two cases?

Comment: [corrections: My understand**ing**. can be pronounce**d**; in both case**s**]

Comment: Rhythmic clipping and pre-fortis clipping apply independently of one another. For _absolute_ vs _apsolute_, rhythmic clipping applies in both words, whereas pre-fortis clipping applies only in the latter. The fact that there is no such word as _apsolute_ makes it harder to determine whether they would be consistently distinguished, of course, but I would definitely distinguish _apsis_ and _abscess_ (the latter is more commonly pronounced /ˈabsɛs/, but I’m only talking about the also relatively common variant /ˈabsɪs/ here).

Comment: You cross posted this with another site. Acoustic is wrong here.

Comment: @Lambie, which site? I posted only here. Plus why acoustic is wrong?

Comment: Because in phonology/phonetics etc, acoustic is not used. Acoustic refers to the sounds made within a space. The acoustics of the concert hall were wonderful. For example.

Comment: @Lambie, I knew that that's why I put "/" between.

Comment: @Lambie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_phonetics

Comment: @Lambie What are you on about? The term acoustic is used ALL THE TIME in phonetics, and acoustic phonetics is one of the primary subdivisions of the field along with articulatory and auditory.

Comment: " /ˈæbs.ə.luːt/ and /ˈæps.ə.luːt/ in normal speech?" does not exist in English. And acoustic phonetics would not be relevant here.

Comment: @Lambie I don't mean to be rude, but acoustic phonetics is (very) obviously relevant since it's what Tran is asking about. But yes, the existence of /ˈæps.ə.luːt/ as a "normal" phonemic structure for the word absolute is questionable.

Comment: @GrahamH. Yes, that's right what I'm asking about. As I understand, /ps/ and /bs/ are (generally) phonemically different, just as /st/ and /sd/ (I'm not sure if there're some modern developments don't regard them as different, but that's what I know of so far). And I also don't think even native speakers can notice the difference. More importantly, if no no difference is perceived by the human ear, then any difference in the acoustic feature (things like spectrogram analysis, F1, F2, etc., where I'm absolutely a total muggle).

Comment: Ohm, on second thought, if /st/ and /sd/ aren't perceived differently by human ears, then /st/ and /sd/ shouldn't be phonemically different, should it?

Comment: @GrahamH. I just don't see why acoustic phonetics has to do with: "My understanding is that "b" in "absolute" can be pronounced either as /b/ or /p/".  In French, the word absolument is: IPA(key): /ap.sɔ.ly.mɑ̃/ Perhaps that's where this comes from...

Comment: @Lambie As I implied, I cannot provide an answer to this question because am I uncertain of the truthfulness of Tran's idea that absolute can have either /b/ or /p/ (I have never heard anyone say they have /p/ in that word). But if that is indeed the case, it is obviously relevant to ask what acoustic differences exist between phonetic realizations of the /b/ and /p/ versions.

Comment: The Vietnamese often have a special relationship with French. It is in French, where that /b/ pronounced like /p/, exists. I can't imagine where else this idea sprang from. Not anything in English itself.

Comment: @Lambie Well I guess you havent read about energy assimilation. The specific case is mentioned in the book *Practical English Phonetics and Phonology*.

Comment: They mention absolute versus apsolute?? The latter is just not a word in English.

Comment: Perhaps you should read about what I mentioned first and also it's better if you can correct the typos directly rather than listing them in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no word "apsolute" in English. You can collect myriad tokens of "absolute" and sort them in terms of the persistence of voicing into the labial, then picking out examples that are "most-voiced" vs. "least-voiced". Next, you can submit the tokens to native speakers and get their reactions. If the test is an A-B pair and the question is whether the words are the same, the answer is 100% of the time "the words are the same".

If the question is "Are A and B the exact same recording" and you have trained them on audible non-linguistic differences (e.g. duration differences, amplitude, noise overlay...) there is a point where speakers can perceive absolute differences, and a point where the differences cannot be perceived. Speakers are highly variable in their skills at this task.

Nobody has performed the second kind of test for "absolute".

Comment: Did you mean "submit the audio recordings" instead of "submit the tokens"? I often think of a token as a string of characters/symbols.

Comment: @Tran A token is “an individual occurrence of a linguistic unit in speech or writing” – it can be an individual instance of someone saying a word just as well as it can be a string of characters or symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The way most people I've heard say it, they sort of say ˈæbp.sə.luːt. Nobody really seems to notice the difference.

Comment: I don't think /ˈæbp.sə.luːt/ is correct, it has a larger mora than necessary.

Comment: I think that [bp] sequence would be better represented as [bʔ], although I'm not sure that's accurate to most speakers. You could actually also use [b̰].

Comment: What I meant is that I sort of hear the b and p mixed.